# Efficient way to write XML files in R

Tags: r

I have a large `xts` object:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(data.frame(P1=c(1:8760),P2=c(1:8760)), order.by = 
     seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct("2023-01-01 00:00", tz="UTC"), 
                to=as.POSIXct("2023-12-31 23:00",tz="UTC"), by = "hour"))
```

which I need to write to disk as XML file (it needs to be read by the hydrological software `Delft-FEWS`). My approach works, but takes plenty of time:

```
library(XML)

TZ = newXMLNode("timeZone", "0.0", parent = root)

s1 <- Sys.time()

# loop over columns
for(p in 1:ncol(x)){

 locId <- colnames(x)[p]
 startDate <- as.character(min(index(x)))
 endDate <- as.character(max(index(x)))

 # create series information
 series <- newXMLNode("series", parent = root)

 # create header
 header <- newXMLNode("header", parent = series)
 type <- newXMLNode("type", "instantaneous", parent = header)
 locationId <- newXMLNode("locationId", locId, parent = header)
 timeStep <- newXMLNode("timeStep", attrs = c(unit = "hour", multiplier = '1'), parent = header)
 startdate <- newXMLNode("startDate", attrs = c(date = startDate, time = "01:00:00"), parent = header)
 enddate <- newXMLNode("endDate", attrs = c(date = endDate, time = "01:00:00"), parent = header)
 mv <- newXMLNode("missVal", -999.0, parent = header)

 # loop over rows
 for(n in 1:nrow(x)){
   DATE <- as.character(format(index(x)[n], format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
   HOUR <- as.character(format(index(x)[n], format = "%H:%M:%S"))
   events <- newXMLNode("event", attrs = c(date = DATE, time = HOUR, value = as.character(round(x[n,p]),2)), parent = series)
 }
}

s2 <- Sys.time()

s2 - s1
```

[1] Time difference of 6.68596 mins

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to avoid the inner loop and create your `event` nodes as  character strings which could then be added to your XML document via `parseXMLAndAdd` . This way we can make use of vectorisation and speed up the creation of the XML document considerably:

```r
library(XML)
library(xts)
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

x <- xts(data.frame(P1 = seq(8760), P2 = seq(8760)),
  order.by =
    seq.POSIXt(
      from = as.POSIXct("2023-01-01 00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      to = as.POSIXct("2023-12-31 23:00", tz = "UTC"),
      by = "hour"
    )
)

events_xml <- function(x, p) {
  paste0(
    "<event date=\"", format(index(x), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "\" ",
    "time=\"", format(index(x), format = "%H:%M:%S"), "\" ",
    "value=\"", as.vector(x[, p]), "\"/>",
    collapse = ""
  )
}

s1 <- Sys.time()

doc <- newXMLDoc()

root <- newXMLNode("Root", doc = doc)

TZ <- newXMLNode("timeZone", "0.0", parent = root)

startDate <- as.character(min(index(x)))
endDate <- as.character(max(index(x)))

for (p in names(x)) {
  locId <- p

  series <- newXMLNode("series", parent = root)

  header <- newXMLNode("header", parent = series)
  type <- newXMLNode("type", "instantaneous", parent = header)
  locationId <- newXMLNode("locationId", locId, parent = header)
  timeStep <- newXMLNode("timeStep", attrs = c(unit = "hour", multiplier = "1"), parent = header)
  startdate <- newXMLNode("startDate", attrs = c(date = startDate, time = "01:00:00"), parent = header)
  enddate <- newXMLNode("endDate", attrs = c(date = endDate, time = "01:00:00"), parent = header)
  mv <- newXMLNode("missVal", -999.0, parent = header)

  parseXMLAndAdd(
    events_xml(x, p),
    series
  )
}

s2 <- Sys.time()

s2 - s1
#> Time difference of 0.096385 secs
```